# Powershell outputs Directory paths differently sometimes

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm using `ls` to find directories by convention.  It works in that it finds them, but I'm piping the results to other functions.  Depending on the way 'ls' (aka: `dir`) is called.  Why is this happening?

```
C:\tmp40D4> ls *_Pkg -Recurse | %{"$_"}
C:\tmp40D4\sub\A_Pkg
C:\tmp40D4\sub\B_Pkg
C:\tmp40D4\sub\C_Pkg

C:\tmp40D4> ls sub *_Pkg -Recurse | %{"$_"}
A_Pkg
B_Pkg
C_Pkg
```

Both results are a list of DirectoryInfo instances.

```
C:\tmp40D4> ls sub *_Pkg -Recurse | %{$_.GetType()}

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     DirectoryInfo                            System.IO.FileSystemInfo
True     True     DirectoryInfo                            System.IO.FileSystemInfo
True     True     DirectoryInfo                            System.IO.FileSystemInfo
```

Comment: My understanding is: "ls" is the alias for "get-childitem". When you are under "tmp40D4", it shows full path (absolute path) since the *_pkg files are not "children" of the directory you are currently under. But when you specify "sub" they all show relative path since in that situation *_pkg file are "children" of the "sub" directory.

Comment: And if you want absolute path in the second command you can go this way: `ls sub *_Pkg -Recurse | %{"$_.Fullname"}`

Comment: @Peter I'm not actually under sub.  I'm using sub as the path to ls.  "$_" simply delegates to write-host by default so it's something about the constructed DirectoryInfo instances that are different.  I find that odd.

Comment: @Peter FullPath for both situations provides the same value.  A full path.

Comment: That is expected if you use fullname. That is why you never get trouble when using $_.fullname.

Comment: I delete one the comments. My little test shows: when you specify `working directory` you will get relative path for the target files right underneath `working directory`; when you don't specify `working directory` you will get FULL PATH for the target files. Anyway, if you use "$_.Fullname" always, you will not have headache:)

Comment: Thanks Peter - FullPath is the route I will go, but I'm still curious about why.  Also, you may consider editing your comments to use `-Path` instead of *working directory* which is not a named parameter.

Comment: I'd like to but since it has been marked as useful so it is not editable. If you marked it can you make it "unuseful" so I can mofidy? strange request indeed :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33645/discussion-between-ryan-cromwell-and-peter)

Comment: can not chat right now. I need another 20 reputation points to chat :)

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, the DirectoryInfo instances provided from the alternative calls to `ls` result in different DirectoryInfo instances.  Specifically,

`ls sub *_Pkg -Recurse | %{ [io.path]::IsPathRooted($_) }` will result in

```
False
False
False
```

while `ls *_Pkg -Recurse | %{ [io.path]::IsPathRooted($_) }` will result in

```
True
True
True
```

It's important to remember that the `ls` doesn't actually *display* anything. `"$_"` in `%{ "$_" }` is shorthand for `write-host $_` which is equivalent to `write-host $_.ToString()`.

So it turns out that ToString() on **non-rooted** DirectoryInfo will result in just the `Name`, where-as ToString() on a **rooted** will use the `FullName`.

Comment: I like this approach. I believe whether you getting fullname or name is coming from how "get-chileitem" (ls) cmdlet makes calls base on different parameter situations given.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `dir` is smart in the sense that it tries to display you with relative paths, but only in trivial cases.

You can enforce the use of absolute paths always by using `-Include *`. In your case:

```
ls sub *_Pkg -Include * -Recurse | %{"$_"}
```

For more info, see documentation on [Get-ChildItem Cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176841.aspx) (for which both `dir` and `ls` are aliases).

Comment: I didn't consider that the DirectoryInfo items themselves might be different

Comment: @jsalonen is trying to give you a way to retrive "$_.Fullname". What you missed in the original question is the difference between "$_.Name" and "$_.Fullname". Talking about paths, you can get some troubles sometimes when using "$_.Name". But you will never get trouble if you use "$_.Fullname".

Comment: Can you explain more of why -Include * results in `Write-Host "$_"` outputting fully qualified FullNames?  I find this odd based on the description of that parameter: http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849800.aspx

Comment: @jsalonen It's important to not that ls doesn't actually have any hand in display.  That's all up to write-host.  I'd still like to understand why -Include * makes them rooted paths.  If you can explain that in your answer I will accept it.

Comment: To why `-Include *` works: I cannot figure out that myself either. Maybe it just enforces the internal implementation of `Get-ChildItem` to somehow behave differently. Whatever the reason, the behaviour is incoherent.